# DependencyExtension class typo error symfony

Tags: php, symfony, service

sorry i need help please to fix my problem i've an error in symfony about me extension class.

[image: This is my error]

i dont see where is my topy error

service.yml

```
services:
    lapille_plateform.antispam:
        class: LAPILLEPlateformBundle\Antispam\LAPILLEAntispam
```

and my class extension:

```
<?php 

namespace LAPILLE\PlateformBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;

class LAPILLEPlateformExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }
}?>
```

if you can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete the final **?>** of your class file
And define the namespace as

**LAPILLEPlateformBundle\DependencyInjection;**

Answer (score 0):

Resolved

problem in my namespace LAPILLE\PlateformBundle

change it to LAPILLEPlateformBundle

thx